# Are the two sentence different or which one is better?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

I wrote a paragraph as follows.

> The experiments proved that the proposed framework A is ﬂexible enough to optimize many models. For example, in the XXX dataset, MetricXX of A is 1, which is 10% greater than that of B.

Then I wrote two kinds of sentences at the end of the paragraph. The XXX in the sentences refers to one kind of conference that the paper was submitted to. The paper is in the discipline of computer science.

> Finally, I was the lead author in a paper I wrote summarizing this work, which was submitted to XXX.

> Finally, I wrote a paper summarizing this work as the first author, which was submitted to XXX.

I do not know which one is better. I think the meaning of the two is same. Maybe the second one is better because its word number is less or it is more comfortable to read?

Answer (score 1):

Having a fewer amount of words doesn't make the sentence better. In the second sentence, you should say you are the lead author, and not the first author because people that aren't familiar with English or English about authors might be confused. It's up to personal preference, and the context.

Comment: Thank you. I think that besides its less words, the second sentence may be more confortable to read for me. I supplement the context in my question. If you have a preference, I am pleased to hear that. And may I ask that why should I use the lead author, rather than the first author at the second sentence? My search in Google shows that the meanings of the two phase are same.

Comment: @allenAn I also searched it up and found that they do in fact mean the same thing. I think using lead author might be a little more clear to people that aren't that familiar with English or English about authors so maybe using lead author would help a little, but you could still use first author.

Comment: OK. And I have supplemented the context in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If we take your example

> Finally, I was the lead author in a paper I wrote summarizing this work, which was submitted to XXX.

I would replace this with

> Finally, I was the lead author on a paper summarizing this work, which was submitted to XXX.

If you are the lead author it is assumed you wrote it, possibly in cooperation with one or more of the other authors. In an academic context *lead author* is fine and unambiguous. As a bonus this version is slightly snappier as it loses a couple of words. I have also replaced *in* with *on* but that is less important. Note that in some disciplines the meaning of priority in the authors list differs but that is more an issue for the Academia stack here.

Comment: Thank you. And I have supplemented in my question that my major is computer science. The paper is in the discipline of computer science.